# XAMPP with apache and mysql already installed

Tags: mysql, apache, installation, xampp

is there any problem to install xampp with apache and mysql already installed?

Comment: I have the same problem. I had aleady installed and uninstalled wamp & when i installed xamp i go eror: Apache service could nor stat -1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem. Just know that you won't be able to start both Apache servers or by MySQL servers at the same time without modifying them to use non-standard ports. (You could easily use the XAMPP MySQL server with your existing Apache or your existing MySQL server with the XAMPP Apache.)

You may also have some problems with registering the XAMPP Apache and MySQL as Windows services using the XAMPP controls if you have your other Apache and MySQL servers configured as services (I'm expecting service name conflicts).

If you already have Apache and MySQL installed on your machine, I'm not sure why you would want to also install XAMPP.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to change the port number from 3306 to 3307 for the pre-existing MySQL server so you can use both MySQL instances (XAMPP MySQL and pre-existing MySQL) simultaneously without conflict.

Answer (score 2):

For personal use? Works fine! Just use the right applications (xampp_start/xampp_stop) to run apache/mysql server!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to consider removing apache and mysql and installing xampp after. Xampp will add both and they might collide if you install xampp and they are already installed.
You should do a backup on your mysql databases and put them back after and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the port number in MySQL installer, you will find an option to reconfigure MySQL server.

Change its port number to `3308` and everything will work fine then.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem, but you need to decide which MySQL server you will use, whether the installed one along XAMPP or the exist MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

If you have Apache and MySQL already installed then why do you need XAMPP?  Surely you already have the full LAMP / WAMP stack already?

Just to add a note.

I had previously installed MySQL server on my local machine for some development projects that didn't require an ..AMP stack.  Mainly NodeJS, Angular and Java applications.

Most of my web development was done on an ubuntu server running a LAMP stack, so I never bothered to set up a local development environment for web development.

In the last couple of days I decided to setup a development environment on my Windows 10 machine using XAMPP (with a MySQL server already running).  Here is what I found:

Running projects that connect to the local MySQL server is not an issue since all the database connections are written in each individual project.  So really, installing MySQL with XAMPP is not a requirement at all.  You can definitely live without it being part of the XAMPP install.

What I did want was the phpmyadmin console for administering the existing MySQL server.  So, I did some digging through the xampp directories.

You can add the username and password of the local MySQL database server in this file:

> /xampp/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

phpMyAdmin will now be accessible via http://localhost/phpmyadmin and will be connected to the existing MySQL installation.

You will also need to create a phpmyadmin database on the local MySQL server to store the phpmyadmin settings, plus a 'pma'@'localhost' account with no password.  Logging into phpyadmin will prompt you for creating the database, just follow the prompts and phpmyadmin will handle the database creation.  The pma (**P**hp**M**y**A**dmin) user will have to be created manually, no password, with full admin permissions.  Now you are good to go...

I tried my best to link the MySQL server to the XAMPP admin console but struggled to get the XAMPP admin console to recognise that the MySQL server was enabled.  I tried editing the path to the mysqld.exe and my-default.ini files in several of the XAMPP files but none made a difference.  I would love to know if this is possible.

Files I edited:

- uMain.pas
- xampp_shell.bat
- MySQL_start.bat
- xampp_start.c
- ctl.bat

Unfortunately none of the edits made a difference.  However, I was still able to admin the MySQL server from phpmyadmin and MySQL Workbench so no loss really.

Hope that helps someone :)

Answer (score -1):

It really easy ...Just u have to stop apache and mysql services manually ..no need to modify any port no.

After that u can start the apache and mysql service through Xammp :)